# What's the best way to edit many objects of a single class in one Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, haml

I'm working on a Rails form that will allow the user to edit the attributes of many objects of a class with a single submission. My initial instinct was to create an outer `form_for` block and then iterate through the items within it using `fields_for`.

However, there is no object that bears a one-many relation to the objects the form will modify, and so it seems to me that there is no object that would be correct to pass into `form_for`.

In any case, what I'd like to see is an example of a form that modifies multiple objects simultaneously without appealing to a "parent" object. Perhaps this will involve `form_tag`?

(Note: I'm working in haml, so answers in haml would be awesome though unnecessary.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, having a parent object will make it easier.

For bulk updates of many objects, the key is to use the right input name so that rails will parse the params as a array, i.e.

```
@posts.each do |post|
  fields_for "posts[#{post.id}]", post do |p|
    p.text_field :name
    p.hidden_field :id
  end
end
```

Have a look at the generated html source to see what name attribute the text input gets. If this is done right, params[:posts] will now be a hash in the controller which you can then update.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple should be relevant too

Comment: Thanks for this response. I hadn't realized that `fields_for` did not need need an object as an argument. In the meantime, I'd arrived at my own solution, which so far seems to be working. I'll post it below.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra wrinkles to my actual situation, but here's some pseudocode that I hope will illustrate the approach I've taken:

```
 = form_tag url_for(:controller => "the_controller",
                     :action => "update") do
     @objects_to_be_updated.each do |object|
       = check_box_tag "[desired_path][through_the][parameters_hash]", true, object.boolean_attibute
       = text_field_tag "[another_path][through_the][parameters_hash]", object.text_attribute
     end
 end
```

And so on.

Using the `_tag` variants of the form helpers, which don't require association with an Active Record model, is a bit of a pain but also seems to give you more control over structure of the resulting parameters.